# How to store preferences in database?

Tags: android, android-preferences

According to documentation there are several ways to store content. One of them is *database*, one of them via *SharedPreferences*.

For my app, I have already a database in use and therefore think the best way would be to store everything in one place, i.e. to store my preferences as well in the database. Searching around, I find only examples which are related to *SharedPreferences*. Defining the preference structure in a xml file has the advantage of easy maintenance, but the disadvantage that background-colors are faulty with sub-menus/sub-screens.

1. Is the approach with *SharedPreferences* appropriate for what I wanna do or do I need to make my own structure (for default values) and  layout resp. view (for presentation)?
2. Does anybody know of valid sample with PreferenceActivity to save settings in the database?  `R.xml.preferences` ==> `PreferenceScreen`?

Answer (score 2):

I would store preferences in `SharedPreferences` - it's what they are there for, there's a whole set of classes and methods for them. You certainly can store them in your own database but you would have to setup the tables, write the adapters, and so on. What's the benefit?

A lot of my apps have an sqlite db in them to store content etc. Preferences I store in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: the main benefit I see is in case of an error due to settings. I would have problems to reapply them. With database not really. Yeah, perhaps with `SharedPreferences`I can write some code to export and reapply them, but then I wanna spend the effort in saving it to database at the start.

Comment: I think you're pre-empting a problem that will probably never happen. :) Good luck!

Comment: Enter submits the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

After looking around I found a [sample](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/09/11/quick-database-row-editor-in-android-09-sdk/) and the final implemented [PreferenceActivity](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/source/browse/src/org/connectbot/HostEditorActivity.java). Based on this I cut out what is not needed and leave the rest (especially the DB-update resp. read-values for an individual implementation. But to be hones, I don't think that would be too difficult.

```
public class MyPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {

  public class CursorPreferenceHack implements SharedPreferences {

    protected Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    private DBPreferences         dbPreferences;

    public CursorPreferenceHack() {
      dbPreferences = new DBPreferences();
      values = dbPreferences.cacheValues();
    }

    public boolean contains(String key) {
      return values.containsKey(key);
    }

    public class Editor implements SharedPreferences.Editor {

      private ContentValues update = new ContentValues();

      public SharedPreferences.Editor clear() {
        update = new ContentValues();
        return this;
      }

      public boolean commit() {
        dbPreferences.updateValues(update);
        // make sure we refresh the parent cached values
        values = dbPreferences.cacheValues();

        // and update any listeners
        for (OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener : listeners) {
          listener.onSharedPreferenceChanged(CursorPreferenceHack.this, null);
        }

        return true;
      }

      // Gingerbread compatibility
      public void apply() {
        commit();
      }

      public android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor putBoolean(String key,
                                                                 boolean value) {
        return this.putString(key, Boolean.toString(value));
      }

      public android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor putFloat(String key,
                                                               float value) {
        return this.putString(key, Float.toString(value));
      }

      public android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor putInt(String key,
                                                             int value) {
        return this.putString(key, Integer.toString(value));
      }

      public android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor putLong(String key,
                                                              long value) {
        return this.putString(key, Long.toString(value));
      }

      public android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor putString(String key,
                                                                String value) {
        update.put(key, value);
        return this;
      }

      public android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor remove(String key) {
        update.remove(key);
        return this;
      }

      public android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor putStringSet(String key,
                                                                   Set<String> value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("HostEditor Prefs do not support Set<String>");
      }
    }

    public Editor edit() {
      return new Editor();
    }

    public Map<String, ?> getAll() {
      return values;
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(String key, boolean defValue) {
      return Boolean.valueOf(this.getString(key, Boolean.toString(defValue)));
    }

    public float getFloat(String key, float defValue) {
      return Float.valueOf(this.getString(key, Float.toString(defValue)));
    }

    public int getInt(String key, int defValue) {
      return Integer.valueOf(this.getString(key, Integer.toString(defValue)));
    }

    public long getLong(String key, long defValue) {
      return Long.valueOf(this.getString(key, Long.toString(defValue)));
    }

    public String getString(String key, String defValue) {
      if (!values.containsKey(key))
        return defValue;
      return (String) values.get(key);
    }

    public Set<String> getStringSet(String key, Set<String> defValue) {
      throw new ClassCastException("HostEditor Prefs do not support Set<String>");
    }

    protected List<OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener> listeners = new LinkedList<OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener>();

    public void registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener) {
      listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener) {
      listeners.remove(listener);
    }

  }

  @Override
  public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode) {
    return this.pref;
  }

  private CursorPreferenceHack  pref;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    this.pref = new CursorPreferenceHack();
    // this.pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
  }
}
```

And for the cacheValues

```
public Map<String, Object> cacheValues() {
    Map<String, Object> retValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       SQLiteDatabase db = dbManager.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(dbTblPref, new String[] { "pref_key", 
        "pref_value" }, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {

        retValues.put(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1));
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    return retValues;
  }
```